# Do i need to update JAVA JDK everytime Oracle releases an update?

Tags: java, java-8

I currently use `JAVA 8` for developing application. The latest version of Java right now is 13. Do I need to switch from `Java 8` to `Java 13`? Why and why not?

Comment: That is a licensing and support question. I would suggest you read the [Oracle Java SE Support Roadmap](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/java-se-support-roadmap.html). Of note, *Java SE 8 has gone through the End of Public Updates process for legacy releases.  Oracle will continue to provide free public updates and auto updates of Java SE 8 from Oracle at java.com, until at least the end of December 2020 for Personal, Development and other Users.*

Comment: Personally, I would suggest it is a great time to [adopt open jdk](https://adoptopenjdk.net/).

Comment: At least update to the next LTS version of Java

Comment: You don't need to upgrade, but you won't get any new features or security fixes. If there is a known security problem in JDK 8, and JDK 8 is at the end of its lifetime, you may not get a fix, and your setup will be vulnerable. Same thing for 3rd party libraries you use --- they may require a certain version of the JDK, so if some library reqires JDK 9 and you are still on 8, you may not get new features or patches.

Upgrading is easier if you do it in small steps, not 5 versions at a time, so I'd recommend updating on a regular basis.

Comment: You don't need to upgrade to every single release but you should put a plan in place for regular updates at intervals that suit you or your customers, to ensure you aren't stil running Java 1.1.2 in the year 2030. And of course there will be new features you need to take advantage of here and there.

Comment: we _do_ upgrade to every single release, around once 1/2 - 1 year (at least docker images that I am involved in). I am granted time and regression for that, if I present arguments some pieces are re-written to take into account the new improved changes. This _has_ bitten us once or twice where there were issues in `JIT` compiler, but nothing that is not fixable. But it's entirely the politics of the company you are are involved in.